# How to insert lines from one file to another file using shell commands?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to write 8 lines from `file1` at the beginning of `file2`.

My `file1` contains the following lines:

```
$BQ  
{ VOL       @home    }  
database    daba  
relation    tcdeatid  
copy           1  
{ version        0 }  
opendb  
clear
# other stuff
```

My `file2` contains the following lines:

```
.lruno := 72  
.infno := 1    
writedb     
clear
```

My output file will be:

```
$BQ  
{ VOL       @home    }  
database    daba  
relation    tcdeatid  
copy           1  
{ version        0 }  
opendb  
clear  
.lruno := 72  
.infno := 1    
writedb       
clear
```

Comment: Does file1 have more than 8 lines and you just want the first 8, or do you mean that you want all of file1 put before file2? Solutions can be different depending on which you mean, and if the intent wasn't just 8 lines but all of the file, you should remove my edit.

Comment: yes file 1 have only 8 lines and I want only first 8lines of file1 to be put before the lines of file2.

Comment: "head -n8 file1 | cat - file2 > file2" and "paste -sd'\n' file1 file2" results same output.

Comment: But the results differ if the newline in `file1` is in a different place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
head -n8 file1 | cat - file2 > file2."$$" && mv file2."$$" file2
```

Comment: @mikeserv... yes it worked...

Comment: also this "paste -sd'\n' file1 file2" worked. Thanks to both of you... @cuonglm

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with standard tools.

With `paste`:

```
paste -sd'\n' file1 file2
```

With `sed`:

```
sed p file1 file2
```

Comment: In case you missed [it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209308/how-to-insert-lines-from-one-file-to-another-file-using-shell-commands/209310?noredirect=1#comment354897_209310).

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file1 file2 > output_file
```

Cat is short for concatenate which is what you are trying to do. 
If you want to keep the results in file1, you could just add them to the end:

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

Notice that in the first case output_file will be truncated (using `>`). Using a double will append (`>>`)

Answer (score 1):

With [`ed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)

```
ed file2 <<END
0r file1
w
q
END
```

at line "0", read in the file "file1", save and exit

As a one-liner: `printf "%s\n" "0r file1" w q | ed file2`